# Update panel textchanged problem asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

After leaving the textbox, I want it to focus on the next object. Or I want the button to work when I click the button. In the problem I'm having right now, I'm having the problem in the gif after leaving the textbox.

---

**default.aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">İşlem Tutarı</label>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTutar" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm price" AutoPostBack="true" placeholder="0,00 ₺" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtTutar_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Tahsil Edilen Tutar</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTahsilEdilen" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="money form-control form-control-sm price" placeholder="0,00 ₺" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtTahsilEdilen_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtTutar" EventName="TextChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

**default.asp.cs**

```
protected void txtTutar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTutar.Text = FormatMoney(decimal.Parse(txtTutar.Text));
    txtTahsilEdilen.Text = txtTutar.Text;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You HAVE BEEN TOLD already that it makes ZERO sense to trigger the same update panel you are already in. And WHERE is the control for this  "  txtTahsilEdilen.Text = txtTutar.Text;   ".  You cannot uppdate controls outside of the update panel in code behind. Either post more markup, or explain where/why this control eixsts on the page: "txtTahsilEdilen.Text = txtTutar.Text;"

Comment: I updated the question. The triggered object is already in the update panel. I want the value written in the object named txtTutar in UpdatePanel1 to be written into the object named txtTahsilEdilen in UpdatePanel2. I can do what I want. But when I press the "tab" key after entering data into the txtTutar object or when I click on any object on the page, the object I click does not focus.

Comment: Full or just update panel post back? That markup travelling up to the server - code behind runs, and then a whole new fresh copy of the update panel is then sent back to the client side. Just like any web page post back, the cursor starts at the first control. You would have to introduce a control.Focus(). You probably can click two times, and does the focus occur? Your post back is due to that click but REALLY due to text changed event. I would remove text changed server side event. You have to consider a ajax call in place of a server side event, and remove text changed event.

Comment: So LITTLE surprise. The click event to jump to a new control is not the issue - it is the fact that text changed posts back the whole update panel, and thus your click even never gets a chance to run. When you click to new control, you post-back due to text changed. You have to really dump that text changed event, since if it fires, then the standard round trip for the panel occurs, code behind runs, and fresh new copy of panel travels back to client side. You always lose the click event as a result.

Comment: Are you using the ajaxToolkit - it has a currency input mask. The other idea would be to use  jQuery plug-in for masked money input.

Comment: See my suggestions below.

Answer (score 0):

I would do one of several things. First up, with the post back occurring (text changed), then when you click on another control - you would in theory have to click two times.

So, either remove the text changed post-back, and format the number WHEN done. if you really want this to occur during typing, then

If you using the ajax control toolkit, there is a really nice number/currency formatter.

if not, then consider a jQuery plugin - it will remove the need for a post-back, and you do this client side. there is a REALLY nice JavaScript library here for this:

https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/

The other easy way - probably the least effort?

use a ajax call based on text changed. That will allow you to run the code behind for the one text box, and now update panel post-back will NOT occur.

So you could code out the textbox like this:

```
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" onchange="fixnum(this)"
            ClientIDMode="Static"
            ></asp:TextBox>
         
        <script>
            function fixnum(c) {
                tBox = $(c)
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      data: JSON.stringify({ v: tBox.val() }),
                      contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      async: true,
                      url: "WebForm4.aspx/curFormat",
                      success: function (MyReturn) {
                          tBox.val(MyReturn.d);
                      },
                      failure: function () {
                          tBox.val("")
                      }
                  });
              }
        </script>
```

And in the web page, we have:

```
 using System.Web.Services;
```

And then a public web method, say like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string curFormat(string v)
    {
        Debug.Print("web call");

       v = String.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(v));
        return v;
    }
```

So, now when you type in a number, and hit tab - we don't do a post-back but do get to run the code behind stub. In fact, you probably could wind up as a result removing the whole need for the update panel.